# Записать массив объектов из текстового файла js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужно заполнить массив объектов (questions) из текстового файла (questions.txt например).

Как это сделать? Пробую так:

```
    var questions = [//Массив объектов содержит вопросы сколько угодно
    {//объект вопрос
        q: "Наименьшая еденица измерения иформации?",//q: "Вопрос"
        a: ["бит","байт","кБайт"],//a: [1,3,"q"] // массив ответов
        trueAnswer: 0//Индекс в массиве a, правильного ответа
    },
    {
        q: "Выберите язык программирования...",
        a: ["Javascript","HTML","CSS"],
        trueAnswer: 0
    },
    {
        q: "Что такое ПК?",
        a: ["Прибор калибровки","Персональный компьютер","Пожарный кран","Прикуриватель карманный"],
        trueAnswer: 1
    }//И так далее можно добавлять сколько угодно
];
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71285/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Comment: Яааасно.... Вы же понимаете, что переменные в php файлах не сохраняются? Откуда же вы их тогда берёте.. Вы сделали запрос, получили ответ, и всё, ничего не сохраняется, файл не продолжает работать с этими переменными